# Can I override Ansible SSH key inventory variable ansible_ssh_private_key_file on command line?

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys, ansible-inventory

In Ansible 2.4.2.0, can I override the SSH key set in inventory with `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` on command line? It is not possible with `--private-key` option as reported on this issue: [Command-line flags (variable weight) not respected (bug or a feature?)](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11991)

The inventory file:

```
[group1]
instance1   ansible_host=host1  ansible_user=user1  ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/user1host1-id_rsa
```

Command line:

```
ansible-playbook playbook1.yml --private-key=some_other-id_rsa
```

Comment: There's an answer in the thread you linked to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override any variable using `--extra-vars` parameter which [takes the priority over variables defined in any other place](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable):

```
ansible-playbook playbook1.yml --extra-vars="ansible_ssh_private_key_file=some_other-id_rsa"
```

Comment: Oh, of course, I saw the discussion about `-e` on the issue tracker page but didn't realize that `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` in `hosts.ini` is just a variable after all! Thank you!